# ASP.NET permission denied in database (example from w3cShools)

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I saw that this is common problem, however did not manage to solve it yet.

It's about example from http://www.w3schools.com/ASPnet/mvc_models.asp

This example uses SQL Server Compact Local Database (SDF), but I need it with SQL Server Database File (MDF).

I got following error:

> CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>   Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: CREATE DATABASE
>   permission denied in database 'master'.

This is connectionString in my Web.config file:

```
  <add
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
    connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|Movies.mdf;InitialCatalog=DatabaseName;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Integrated Security=True;" name="MovieDBContext"  />
```

Can you help me how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Your connection string specifies both a connection to the `DatabaseName` database in LocalDb and a filename. Attachable databases are a feature of SQL Express, not LocalDB so the `AttachDbFileName` property is ignored.

To attach to a file for single use you should use `.\SQLExpress` as the Data Source, eg:

```
Data Source=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|Movies.mdf;...
```

Comment: Nope, still same problem

Comment: Using *which* connection string?

Comment: Is the database file already attached to SQL Express? Another issue may be that the application pool's account may not have permission to connect to SQL Express

Comment: using this one: <connectionStrings><add providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|Movies.mdf;InitialCatalog=DatabaseName;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Integrated Security=True;" name="MovieDBContext" /></connectionStrings>

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your dbcontext class constructor:

```
public class MovieDBContext : DbContext
{
    public MovieDBContext() : base(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager
        .ConnectionStrings["MovieDBContext"].ConnectionString)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This isn't related to the question (the OP didn't even mention EF) *and* it will result in the same error.